# Guardar texto usando savefiledialog y abrirlo con openfiledialog en diferentes textbox?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Lo que necesito es que mi aplicación guarde datos de 2 textbox y un datetimepicker (con savefiledialog) y que si se abre (con openfiledialog) se escriba en diferentes textbox y datetimepicker respectivamente.

Comment: Mira por favor [ask] <- ACA.. y que intentaste hasta ahora? porque lo que pedis no es dificil. Porbaste algo? abriste el archivo? lo guardaste? donde tuviste problemas?

Comment: Los datos ya se guardaron, lo único que necesito es que se abran en diferentes textbox y datetimepicker

Comment: que es que se abran en diferentes textbox y dt? podrias poner un ejemplo y explicar mucho mejor que queres que se abra en un campo de texto?

Comment: Si, exacto, necesito que los datos guardados como archivo con savefiledialog se abran en una textbox y dt

Comment: Sebastian, no estas explicando lo que queres. Solo vos sabes que es que los datos guardados como archivo se muestren en un TXT. Pone un ejemplo, usa el boton [edit], pone que hiciste hasta ahora. La pregunta tiene que ser clara.

Comment: Si no mal entiendo necesitas que si por ejemplo el `TextBox1` contiene "Hola" y el `TextBox2` contiene "Como estas?" y el `DatetimePicker` tiene `2018/03/12` que esos datos se guarden en un TXT, pero si en algún momento abres nuevamente el TXT desde el OpenDialog que esos datos que contiene te los coloque en su respectivo campo, Digase el TextBox1, TextBox2 y DatetimePicker cierto?

Comment: SI, exactamente

Comment: Pregunta: **¿El contenido del TextBox1, TextBox2 y DatetimePicker se guardarán en un archivo, y si cambiar algún dato en la pantalla de las cajas de texto y guardas nuevamente, se guardará en el mismo archivo o un archivo nuevo?** tendrías un problema, porque si todos los datos lo vas a guardar en un mismo TXT como vas a identificar cual dato deseas cargar? debe haber un identificador único por cada linea de texto. O Si usarás un archivo de texto distinto se puede hacer pero no es útil.

Comment: Sabes cómo se podría hacer un identificador?

Comment: Mejor guárdalo en un xml en vez de txt.

Comment: Si lo guardo en un xml, ¿Que beneficios tiene?